# When should public variables be used?

Tags: java, android

Using the android developer page for ScanResult, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html, I noticed that they have public variables BSSID, SSID, capabilities, etc. I thought this was weird, as using getters/setters over public variables is the java norm. Is there a broad, rule-based reason why public variables are sometimes used over getters/setters?

Comment: Questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are not well-suited for Stack Overflow. Usually, the only party that definitively knows the answer is Developer X, and Developer X is unlikely to see your question. Anyone else can only offer an opinion. In this case, the decision was made over a decade ago. Now, they're stuck with it, for backwards-compatibility reasons.

Comment: @CommonsWare I was wondering if there were rules on public variables that had exceptions. For example, if objects usually found in a list and only in a list could have public variables and still considered fitting the java OOP.

Comment: You might have better luck, then, if you rephrase the question. Using `ScanResult` as an example of a broader class design question is fine, but as written, your question is about `ScanResult` itself.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see your point and edited the question to be more broad, using ScanResult only as an example. Thank you for helping me learn about asking the right questions on stackoverflow!

Comment: I've always personally though if you have a public setter and getter and they don't "do anything" other than setting and getting they are basically just noise over a public member. (The thing to take away from this is if you have loads of getters and setters you're probably doing it wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example you mentioned, they are really public variables and that is bad practice. Strange why they made them public. This breaks encapsulation - the principle of hiding data in order to be able to control precisely who and when the data gets set.

But if you think, what's the point in making members private and allowing just dumb getters and setters? It's the same as setting them directly.

And the answer is this:
1. If you make the fields public, it would be impossible to change the API of your classes and if you decide later you want to put some logging or security constraints in the getters or setters, you won't be able to make those fields private without breaking people's code.
2. Getters and setters allow for overriding in child classes.
and many other advantages.

So in conclusion - it is stupid to make these fields public. Not expecting that from Google engineers. Also they made the class extend Object (which is by default the case in java)

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. You're right! I didn't think about the variables in the context of the problem, as there is no reason to change them. While the page does not state they are final, which originally made me think they weren't constants, nothing is achieved by changing these variables. It is akin to receiving data and deciding you don't like it, so you write over it.

Comment: While there are constants on `ScanResults`, there are also many `public` non-`final` fields, [such as `BSSID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html#BSSID).

Answer (score 0):

- Keep variables private by default
- Variables that need to be accessed from **outside** a package should use accessor methods (getters / setters)
- Variables used only within a private package can safely be made "public"